# C# How to write events to Security and Maintenance

Tags: c#, windows, events

I need some assistance. I have a Windows service (that I'm coding myself) which writes all necessary data (Information, Warnings, Errors) to Event Viewer in Windows 10, and that's works fine (I'm using EventLog). However I know, that windows 10 also has a Security and Maintenance (in Control Panel) which looks similar to Event Viewer (as for me). I'd like to know, if there is any way to write something there, using C# ?

On the first screenshot, you can see what I currently have.
On the second, what I want

```
EventLog myEventLog = new EventLog();
            myEventLog.Source = "ABCD";
            myEventLog.Log = myLogName;


            string myMessage = "Testing 1.2.3...";
            EventLogEntryType myEventLogEntryType = EventLogEntryType.Warning;
            int myApplicatinEventId = 1234;
            short myApplicatinCategoryId = 1;
            Console.WriteLine("Writing to EventLog.. ");
            myEventLog.WriteEntry(myMessage, myEventLogEntryType,
               myApplicatinEventId, myApplicatinCategoryId);
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JReSj.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqfgG.png

Comment: Simple answer is *no you can't write to the Reliability Monitor*. The main reason is because this information is pulled from the Event Manager/Log to get the data about your system.

Comment: Ok, thank you! Thats what I thought too :) However, I decided to ask about it)

Comment: You are welcome, good luck!